# how can I use perl-like regular expressions in R to match exact string held within a vector?

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing a number of similar IDs and associated information:

```
col1 = c("id_string", "1id_string", "id_string1")    
col2 = c("x", "y", "z")    
col3 = c("d", "e", "f")    
data = data.frame(col1, col2, col3)
```

I have a vector (output from a loop) containing a string that I wish to use for matching:

`id = "id_string"`

I have used grep to match the string held within the vector with all rows in data$col1 containing the string

`grep(id, data$col1)`

However, I wish to extract only the row numbers from data$col1 with the exact string held within id (no characters before / after). How can I achieve this?

Comment: you mean exact match, then why regular expressions? `data[data$col1 == id, ]`?

Comment: yes that works great thanks, I was overcomplicating things...apologies for newb question(!)

Answer (score 3):

If you must use `grep` try

```
data
##         col1 col2 col3
## 1  id_string    x    d
## 2 1id_string    y    e
## 3 id_string1    z    f

grep(paste0("^", id, "$"), data$col1)
## [1] 1
```

Or as @Arun suggested

```
data[data$col1 == id, ]
```

Comment: (+1) for the exact match subsetting. It doesn't make sense to do regexp here.